# Create file with grqphql remix. Shopify

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-api

According to the shopify graphql instructions for [FileCreateInput](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/unstable/input-objects/filecreateinput#top)

FileCreateInput.originalSource
originalSource
String!
non-null
An external URL (for images only) or a staged upload URL.

This shouldn't be required if the contentType is a "FILE".
I run the following query with Remix:

```
`#graphql
mutation fileCreate($files: [FileCreateInput!]!) {
  fileCreate(files: $files) {
    files {
      createdAt
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
`,
{
  variables: {
    files: [
      {
        contentType: "FILE",
        filename: "foobar.liquid",
        originalSource: ""
      },
    ]
  }
},
```

I get the error that:
'Provided filename extension must match original source.'

I also try originalSource: null and "null"
with "null" i get the same error
with null I get
"was provided invalid value for 0.originalSource (Expected value to not be null)"
However I'm not attempting to copy over a file or image I'm simply trying to create a new file.  Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: I've been playing with the fileCreate for the past couple of days, and I think the name is misleading. It's more like fileCopy, meaning the file needs to be uploaded somewhere first. It seems what you want is not possible with this mutation. Maybe look at this resource: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-01/resources/asset#put-themes-theme-id-assets

Comment: Hi I had read that before but unfortunately the Asset api requires special clearance. I believe you're right that the fileCreate is misleading. @Umut

Comment: Yes, I thought maybe your use case is eligible for an exemption since it's a liquid file that you try to create. I just upload to the files section of the admin. I hope you find a solution, and please share your result here. Shopify docs are not the best, people get confused all the time.